# Most efficient method for updating UIButton elements in a collection view for iOS Core data-driven app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, nsfetchrequest

I'm at a bit of a fork in the road and could use some advice. I'm building a sort-of punch card system and saving the state of the punch via core data (See screen shot below) :

Image Link : http://postimg.org/image/idrm8sfr3/

The app basically has a 'dates' collection view at the top. A table view of 'parent items' each with their own collection views of 'reps' or 'punches'. The collection view sync with one another when scrolling left or right in order to correlate to the corresponding date.

I've gotten it to a point where when the user taps a button/'punch' it creates a rep/punch managed object, attaches it to it's parent item (via core data relationships) sets the correlating date value, and turns it ON.

This is all well and good, however now I am trying to figure out the best way to update the UIButton representations of the Managed Reps/punches objects. My current theory is to perform a fetch request on load of the UIButton. This would cycle through the parent item's 'child' items (reps/punches) and search for a matching date. Once it finds an item with the matching date, it response accordingly to the object, in that whether it is on or off. In my mind, since the cells in the collection views are dequed, it would only perform a maximum of about 35 fetch requests at once, since this is all the cells that will fit on the screen. Then it will perform new requests once new cells are loaded. This would prevent having to load every rep/punch object for all of time once the view is loaded.

My other thoughts would be to have a correlating rep/punch managed object created for ever cell and just synchronize the cells based on an index path, however the app would end up having a lot of 'dead' objects that are just sitting there. This seems wasteful and inefficient.

Finally the third option I thought of would be to some how create a dictionary for each parent item's set of child managed objects and make the key be their date values. Then I could simply sync the dictionary keys to the corresponding cell's date values.

I sincerely hope this is not a bunch of gibberish! I'm new to iOS programming and trying my best to convey my challenge with my limited scope. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Relevant code so far :

```
@interface UpdateRepsViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *datesCV;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *habitsTableView;

@end

@implementation UpdateRepsViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // scroll to last item in collection view (ie: today)
    NSInteger lastItem = [[Calculations updateRepsDateRangeDates] count]-1;
    NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:lastItem inSection:0];
    [self.datesCV scrollToItemAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight animated:YES];
    self.horScrollPos = self.datesCV.contentOffset.x;
    NSLog(@"%f", self.horScrollPos);

    // hides separator lines
    self.habitsTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);
        abort();
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - managedObjectContext Reference
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    return [(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}

#pragma mark - Scroll Sync & Control

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == self.datesCV) {
        for (UpdateRepsHabitCell *x in [self.habitsTableView visibleCells]) {
            x.repsCV.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0);
        }
    }
    if (scrollView.tag == 5) {
        for (UpdateRepsHabitCell *x in [self.habitsTableView visibleCells]) {
            x.repsCV.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0);
        }
        self.datesCV.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0);
    }
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    self.horScrollPos = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    NSLog(@"%f", self.horScrollPos);
}

#pragma mark - CollectionViews Data Source

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (collectionView == self.datesCV) {
        return [[Calculations updateRepsDateRangeDates] count];
    }
    if (collectionView.tag == 5) {
        return [[Calculations updateRepsDateRangeDates] count];
    }
    else return 3;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (collectionView == self.datesCV) {
        UpdateRepsDateCell *cell = (UpdateRepsDateCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"DateCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"EEEEE\nM/d"];

        cell.date.text = [df stringFromDate:[Calculations updateRepsDateRangeDates][indexPath.row]];
        return cell;
    }
    if (collectionView.tag == 5) {
        RepButtonCell *cell = (RepButtonCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"RepCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // get cell date
        NSDate *cellDate = [Calculations updateRepsDateRangeDates][indexPath.row];

        // get parent habit
        UpdateRepsRepCV * urcv = (UpdateRepsRepCV *)collectionView;
        Habit *habit = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:urcv.habitIndexPath];

        // show relevant buttons
        if ([cellDate compare:habit.startDate] >= 0) {
            cell.repButton.hidden = NO;
        }
        else {
            cell.repButton.hidden = YES;
        }

        cell.repButton.habitIndexPath = urcv.habitIndexPath;
        cell.repButton.cellIndexPath = indexPath;

        return cell;
    }
    else {
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc]init];
        return cell;
    }
}

#pragma mark - Habits Table View Data Source

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController.sections objectAtIndex:section];
    return [secInfo numberOfObjects];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UpdateRepsHabitCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HabitCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Habit *habit = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.habitName.text = habit.name;

    cell.parentTableView = self.habitsTableView;

    cell.repsCV.habitIndexPath = indexPath;

    // set scroll
    cell.repsCV.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.horScrollPos, 0);

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsController

-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Habit" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"sortOrder" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil]];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsController Delegate Methods

-(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.habitsTableView beginUpdates];
}

-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.habitsTableView endUpdates];
}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.habitsTableView;

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: {
            Habit *changedHabit = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            UpdateRepsHabitCell *cell = (UpdateRepsHabitCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.habitName.text = changedHabit.name;
        }
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.habitsTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.habitsTableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

#pragma mark - IBActions

- (IBAction)repPressed:(id)sender {

    // get parent habit
    RepButton *repButton = (RepButton *)sender;
    Habit *parentHabit = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:repButton.habitIndexPath];

    // get date
    NSDate *repDate = [Calculations updateRepsDateRangeDates][repButton.cellIndexPath.row];


    Rep *rep = (Rep*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Rep" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    rep.habit = parentHabit;
    rep.date = repDate;
    rep.completed = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

    NSError *error;
    if ( ! [[self managedObjectContext]save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"An error! %@", error);
    }
}
```